# reading an xml value in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

i have checked around the site and although many people are looking for similar solutions, a solution to my specific problem has not been posted, nor has a similar question been asked.

i have an XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
 <item1>TEXT A</item1>
 <item2>TEXT B</item2>
 <subs>
  <sub1>
   <thing property1='valueA' property2='valueB'>
    <foo>fooA</foo>
  </sub1>
  <sub2>
   <thing property1='valueC' property2='valueD'>
    <foo>fooA</foo>
  </sub2>
 </subs>
</root>
```

i want to get "TEXT B"

i am thinking

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(MY_XML_FILE)
```

but now how do i access "TEXT B" ??

```
xml.root.item2.text
```

does not work. any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things going on here:

1. Groovy's XmlParser and XmlSlurper (I recommend the latter) take an XML document wrapped in a root element (well-formed XML always exists in a root element). Groovy doesn't require you to specify the root element, so

   xml.root.item1

can become

```
xml.item1
```

If you have many item1s, you need to access them as an array.

```
xml.item1[0]
```

1. Your XML is not well-formed. You're missing two  end tags.
2. To get the inner text of a node, use text() instead of text (it's a method).

Here are some excellent resources on both [XmlParser](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser) and [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper).

Comment: the syntax of slurper is the same as parser i assume? so i can use xml.item1.text() and it should give me what i want? this isnt my actual xml it was something i recreated, i forgot to close the tags but it should work in reality. thank you thank.

Comment: Parser and Slurper have slightly different syntaxes as far as navigating the tree goes. Slurper tends to feel less verbose and more "DSL-ey", but they both do the same thing. (Although, I would suggest using JSON as a data interchange format - Groovy's JsonParser maps JSON straight into a bona-fide object!)